# Speech to text with IBM watson for live RTP/VOIP/Audio call is not converting to text

Tags: speech-recognition, speech-to-text, ibm-watson, watson

i am trying to make use of speech to text service by IBM watson serivce but i am facing some issues in converting speech to text.

Could you please help me out with the following scenario?.

I have setup VOIP(Asterisk/freeswitch) server with A SIP client and B SIP client registered, and A called B, call is established they are taking over phones using G711 ULAW codec .

I have websocket application that connects to IBM watson speech to text and session is established. I got the reply from watson server as "State listening".

Now i am trying to send raw rtp packet data from VOIP server to watson server but i am getting "session timeout" error from watson.

Following configuration parameters i am using.

Since this is live RTP audio call i am using 
en-US_NarrowbandModel
'Content-type':audio/l16;rate=16000

I am continuously sending raw data of RTP packets over websocket connection of watson server.

Please help me with what i am doing wrong with this setup.

Answer (score 0):

Hello @ram what do you mean with "i am trying to send raw rtp packet data"? the Watson STT service does not support RTP packets directly, you need to convert that to a supported audio format. Did you convert the RTP packets to `audio/l16;rate=16000` before feeding them over the websocket?

this is the list of supported formats:

```
audio/basic (Use only with narrowband models.)
audio/flac
audio/l16 (Specify the sampling rate (rate) and optionally the number of channels (channels) and endianness (endianness) of the audio.)
audio/mp3
audio/mpeg
audio/mulaw (Specify the sampling rate of the audio.)
audio/ogg (The service automatically detects the codec of the input audio.)
audio/ogg;codecs=opus
audio/ogg;codecs=vorbis
audio/wav (Provide audio with a maximum of nine channels.)
audio/webm (The service automatically detects the codec of the input audio.)
audio/webm;codecs=opus
audio/webm;codecs=vorbis
```

https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/speech-to-text/api/v1/#recognize_audio_websockets